# GoogleAds conversion - multiple network requests - what for?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

When I implement a GoogleAds conversion event I recognize multiple network requests to various domains. Can someone explain what (and why) is happening here?

I got the idea of providing information about a certain event to a specific endpoint (or monitoring system -> GoogleAds) but I do not understand the different purposes of these multiple requests.

**Code Example**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XYZ";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'AW-XYZ');

gtag('event', 'conversion', {
'send_to': 'AW-XYZ/abc123',
'transaction_id': '123456789'
});
```

**Network Requests**

*Domain:* googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XYZ
*Status:* 200
*Type:* Script

*Domain:* googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/...
*Status:* 200
*Type:* script

*Domain:* googleadservices.com/pagead/...
*Status:* 200
*Type:* script

*Domain:* googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/...
*Status:* 302
*Type:* gif

*Domain:* google.com/pagead/...
*Status:* 302
*Type:* gif

*Domain:* google.de/pagead/...
*Status:* 302
*Type:* gif

Comment: Do you have google ads in your page? The code you have looks like it's just for Google Analytics.

Comment: No, the code is fine. Many new Google scripts are hosted on googletagmanager.com - no matter if you use GoogleAds or Analytics. But I am really interested in the purpose of those different server calls.

Answer (score 2):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XYZ";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
```

Inits download of **gtag core** library from
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XYZ

```
gtag('config', 'AW-XYZ');
```

Init gtag's tracker.

**Next**, you track conversion:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
'send_to': 'AW-XYZ/abc123',
'transaction_id': '123456789'
});
```

JavaScript for **conversions** is downloaded:

```
https://www.google.com/pagead/conversion_async.js
```

**It makes first** tracking request.

This goes into https://www.google.com/**pagead/1p-conversion**/XYZ/

**Cookie is dropped:**

```
SIDCC=AJi4QfEKDZ05LwN4g23OLyoW…in=.google.com; priority=high

Permanent Cookies   
SIDCC   AJi4QfEKDZ05LwN4g23OLyoW017
Expires Fri, 02-Jul-2021 10:46:18 GMT
Domain  .google.com
Path    /
Other attributes    
priority    high
```

Then Doubleclick (in this case a DMP platform) is contacted.

https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/**pagead/viewthroughconversion**/XYZ/

It also contains small JavaScript that makes **doubleclick** request.

```
(function() {
    var s = {};
    (function() {
        /*  Copyright The Closure Library Authors. SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 */
        var c = this || self;
        var f = /#|$/;

        function l(d) {
            var g = d.search(f),
                a;
            a: {
                for (a = 0; 0 <= (a = d.indexOf("fmt", a)) && a < g;) {
                    var b = d.charCodeAt(a - 1);
                    if (38 == b || 63 == b)
                        if (b = d.charCodeAt(a + 3), !b || 61 == b || 38 == b || 35 == b) break a;
                    a += 4
                }
                a = -1
            }
            if (0 > a) return null;
            b = d.indexOf("&", a);
            if (0 > b || b > g) b = g;
            a += 4;
            return decodeURIComponent(d.substr(a, b - a).replace(/\+/g, " "))
        };

        function n(d, g, a) {
            function b() {
                --p;
                if (0 >= p) {
                    var e;
                    (e = d.GooglebQhCsO) || (e = {});
                    var q = e[g];
                    q && (delete e[g], (e = q[0]) && e.call && e())
                }
            }
            for (var p = a.length + 1, m = 0; m < a.length; m++) {
                var h = l(a[m]),
                    k = null;
                1 != h && 2 != h || !(h = d.document.getElementById("goog_conv_iframe")) || h.src || (k = h);
                k || (k = new Image);
                k.onload = b;
                k.src = a[m]
            }
            b()
        }
        var r = ["ss_"],
            t = s || c;
        r[0] in t || "undefined" == typeof t.execScript || t.execScript("var " + r[0]);
        for (var u; r.length && (u = r.shift());) r.length || void 0 === n ? t[u] && t[u] !== Object.prototype[u] ? t = t[u] : t = t[u] = {} : t[u] = n;
    }).call(this);;
    s.ss_(window, 'OjE1OTM2ODY3Nzg2Mjc', ['https://www.google.com/pagead/1p-user-list/XYZ/?random\x3d1593686778627\x26cv\x3d9\x26fst\x3d1593684000000\x26num\x3d1\x26bg\x3dffffff\x26guid\x3dON\x26u_h\x3d920\x26u_w\x3d1472\x26u_ah\x3d920\x26u_aw\x3d1472\x26u_cd\x3d24\x26u_his\x3d3\x26u_tz\x3d120\x26u_java\x3dfalse\x26u_nplug\x3d0\x26u_nmime\x3d0\x26gtm\x3d2oa6o0\x26sendb\x3d1\x26data\x3devent%3Dgtag.config\x26frm\x3d0\x26url\x3dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.optimics.cz%2F\x26tiba\x3dOptimics%20%7C%20Chytr%C3%BD%20online%20marketing%20d%C3%ADky%20analytice\x26async\x3d1\x26fmt\x3d3\x26is_vtc\x3d1\x26random\x3d2253878667\x26resp\x3dGooglemKTybQhCsO\x26rmt_tld\x3d0\x26ipr\x3dy', 'https://www.google.cz/pagead/1p-user-list/XYZ/?random\x3d1593686778627\x26cv\x3d9\x26fst\x3d1593684000000\x26num\x3d1\x26bg\x3dffffff\x26guid\x3dON\x26u_h\x3d920\x26u_w\x3d1472\x26u_ah\x3d920\x26u_aw\x3d1472\x26u_cd\x3d24\x26u_his\x3d3\x26u_tz\x3d120\x26u_java\x3dfalse\x26u_nplug\x3d0\x26u_nmime\x3d0\x26gtm\x3d2oa6o0\x26sendb\x3d1\x26data\x3devent%3Dgtag.config\x26frm\x3d0\x26url\x3dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.optimics.cz%2F\x26tiba\x3dOptimics%20%7C%20Chytr%C3%BD%20online%20marketing%20d%C3%ADky%20analytice\x26async\x3d1\x26fmt\x3d3\x26is_vtc\x3d1\x26random\x3d2253878667\x26resp\x3dGooglemKTybQhCsO\x26rmt_tld\x3d1\x26ipr\x3dy']);
})();
```

**302 Redirect following** this request was in my case unsuccessfull HTTP2 handshake request. With **http2_handshake_failed** base64 encoded information.

Then you are requesting **global** Google user list:

https://www.google.com/**pagead/1p-user-list**/XYZ/

And **local** user list:

https://www.google.de/**pagead/1p-user-list**/XYZ/

> **User lists**
>
> [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/AdwordsUserListService.UserList)
>
> UserList object is a list of users an account may target.

And pixel request setting **test_cookie** checking your privacy options.

This cookies represent your [Google's Ad Settings](https://adssettings.google.com/authenticated).

https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/**pagead/viewthroughconversion**/XYZ/

```
Permanent Cookies   
test_cookie CheckForPermission
Expires Thu, 02-Jul-2020 11:01:19 GMT
Domain  .doubleclick.net
Path    /
Secure  true
Other attributes    
SameSite    none
```

If you are interested more in Google's cookies, follow this link https://www.gresearch.co.uk/cookie-policy/

Comment: thank you! can you elaborate a little bit about the purpose of those requests? why is doubleclick contacted in case of a simple GoogleAds conversion, what about those different "user lists" and why is Google checking my privacy options here?

Comment: @funkfux Hi, Doubleclick is Google's network providing most of services for ad business. It runs multiple products such as Doubleclick, AdWords, Demographic reports in Analytics, etc... User Lists are list of targetable users and Privacy options are related to Ad Settings. I add both into the reply.